# Checking whether there are any cronjobs currently running

Tags: backup, cron

I'm running a webserver in a VM.

In order to create consistent backups, I have to stop Apache, MySQL and other processes for a short time before doing a snapshot of the VM's harddrive (LVM-based).

However, there might be some cronjobs currently running on the VM that need access to the MySQL database. I don't want to interrupt them.

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to determine whether there are currently any cronjobs running. When it's time for a backup, I will wait until I don't "disturb" any cronjob.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ $(ps h --ppid `pidof crond` | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then 
   /run/your/backup
else 
    echo "There are some still running cron jobs."
fi
```

Comment: I guess that's better than "pgrep cron", because the latter would also find any processes that happen to have "cron" in their name, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. `pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes`.

Answer (score 2):

What you really need to do is use a locking system because anything that checks for the existence/non-existence of something leaves a window of opportunity for a process to launch and create the inconsistent state you're tryiung to avoid.

Linux provides the [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) command there is an example of using it [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/376717/how-to-schedule-server-jobs-more-intelligently-than-with-cron/376724#376724).