# Script that checks and runs a jar, sometimes runs it twice.

Tags: bash, java, ps

I jave written a small bash script to run every 10 minutes, check if a certain program is running and if not run it. However, I noticed that sometimes I have two instances of the same program running (using `ps ax | grep "gateway"`). What am I doing wrong?

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                   
case "$(ps ax | grep -c gateway.jar)" in                                       

      1)  echo "Restarting Java Gateway (1):     $(date)" >> /home/user/gateway.log
          java -jar /home/user/project/unx/java/gateway.jar &          
      ;;                                                                         
      0)  echo "Restarting Java Gateway (0):     $(date)" >> /home/iwidgetuser/gateway.log
          java -jar /home/user/project/unx/java/gateway.jar &          
      ;;                                                                         
      *)  echo "Gateway is running! Good!:     $(date)" >> /home/user/gateway.log
      ;;                                                                         
esac
```

Comment: On Linux [flock](http://serverfault.com/questions/376717/how-to-schedule-server-jobs-more-intelligently-than-with-cron/376724#376724) is your friend.

Comment: @Iain, thanks. What do you mean by "/path/to/your/job"? Is it a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check is program is running is incorrect.

You obtain list of running processes and search in them string with your program name (`gateway.jar`). If string occured in processes list 0 or 1 times you start `gateway.jar`.

If `gateway.jar` is still running it will be in process list.
Also, if `grep` invocation was caught in process list, it's command will contain `gateway.jar` and it will be counted by `grep`.

So there are three four cases:

1. `gateway.jar` is running and `grep` is in process list -> `grep` returns 2
2. `gateway.jar` is running and `grep` is not in process list -> `grep` returns 1
3. `gateway.jar` is not running and `grep` is in process list -> `grep` returns 1
4. `gateway.jar` is not running and `grep` is not in process list -> `grep` returns 0

If case 2 happens your code starts `gateway.jar` second time.

Case 2 happens rarely, e.g. on my machine it happened 4 times out of 1000 invocations:

```
$ for i in `seq 1 1000`; do if [ $(ps ax | grep -c abcd) != "1" ]; then echo $i; fi; done
183
377
632
898
$
```

Comment: Thank you. This clarifies a lot. I am trying to use flock. as Iain suggested, but until then. Is there a way to fix my code?

Comment: As a quick fix you can search with regexp pattern that will not match itself, e.g. `$(ps ax | grep -c -E 'gateway\.jar')` will be either `0` or `1`. `-E` enables handling pattern as regexp, and `\.` is escaping of the dot character.