# Ubuntu cron job every workday

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, scheduled-task, ubuntu-16.04

On Ubuntu 16, I'm trying to trigger cron job at 8:00 AM on workdays, and here is what I've tried so far

```
0 8 * * 1-5 /path/to/command
```

and

```
0 8 * * MON-FRI /path/to/command
```

Does not work

Answer (score 15):

These syntaxes are valid for all working days a 8:00 AM :

- `0 8 * * 1-5 /path/to/command >/dev/null 2>&1`
- `0 8 * * 1,2,3,4,5 /path/to/command >/dev/null 2>&1` as you said [@aleksandar-pavić](https://serverfault.com/users/227026/aleksandar-pavi%C4%87)

More explanations with these links :

- https://crontab.guru/#0_8_*_*_1-5
- https://crontab.guru/#0_8_*_*_1,2,3,4,5

The use of `>/dev/null 2>&1` is optional, the goal is to redirect all the outputs to /dev/null.

You must have another problem, you must also specify the user if you use crontab -e

Here is a reminder of the cron syntax

```
* * * * * *
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally tested and found the answer, so 1-5, or MON-FRI does not work, what works is

```
0 8 * * 1,2,3,4,5 /path/to/command
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it looks like you want to run the command on [weekdays](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/weekday), as opposed to [workdays](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/workday).

> weekday: any day of the week except Sunday or, often, Saturday and
>   Sunday.
>
> workday: a day on which work is done; working day.

If you wanted *workdays*, you'd have to schedule a script every day with `cron`, and then build into that script the logic necessary to determine whether "today" is a working day and the command needs to be executed, or not.

Since the question is tagged `ubuntu-16.04`, I had a look at the relevant [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/crontab.5.html) which reads:

> day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
>
> Names  can  also  be used for the `month` and `day of week` fields.
>   Use the first three letters  of  the  particular  day  or  month  (case
>   doesn't matter).  **Ranges or lists of names are not allowed**.

and then tried this crontab on a Ubuntu 16.04 server:

```
  *  *   *   * 1-5   date >> /tmp/date.txt
```

It does yield the desired output:

```
Mon May  1 00:00:25 CEST 2017
Tue May  2 00:00:03 CEST 2017
Wed May  3 00:00:47 CEST 2017
Thu May  4 00:00:01 CEST 2017
Fri May  5 00:00:53 CEST 2017
Fri May  5 00:01:01 CEST 2017
```

This is obtained by setting the system time at 00:00:00 subsequently for each day of the first week of May 2017. The results also highlight that cron does not guarantee execution with a precision interval smaller than one minute (if interested, see a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/721088/how-precise-is-a-cron-daemon) on this topic).

Just out of curiosity, I the tried the following crontab:

```
 *  *   *   * MON-FRI   date >> /tmp/date.txt
```

Surprisingly, and contrary to what the documentation says, it does still work:

```
Mon May  1 00:00:44 CEST 2017
Tue May  2 00:00:39 CEST 2017
Wed May  3 00:00:47 CEST 2017
Thu May  4 00:00:17 CEST 2017
Fri May  5 00:00:10 CEST 2017
```